# Bootstrap 5.2 Equal height cards with three cards, two in the same column

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm not sure how to properly word this question, hence the sketchy title.

I'm using Bootstrap 5.2.3, two-column grid to display three cards.   There is one card in the first column and two cards, one per row, in the second column.

**Code**

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <!-- Content starts here-->
  <div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <div class="card shadow h-100 mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Students</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          Box C
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
      <div class="card shadow h-100 mb-3 ">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Tests</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          content box a
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card shadow h-100 mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Questions</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          content box b
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nbrvqmat/

I've used the h-100 successfully in other parts of my project when there is one on the left and one on the right.

In this scenario, the bottom of the left card, Students, is only extends to the bottom of the first card, Tests.  It should be the bottom of the last card, Questions.

[image: Example]

When I inspect the Row element, it does not contain the Questions card.  The height ends at the bottom of the Students and Tests cards.

[image: Inspect Example]

If I remove the h-100 from both cards, they are contained within the row.

How can I get bottom of the Student card to match the bottom of the Questions card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `col-md-10` you set the first card as `100% height` of its column, which causes the second card to overflow out of `col-md-10` because there is no more vertical space left to allocate.

[Try](https://jsfiddle.net/xecq4ag8/) setting `overflow:hidden` on `col-md-10` and you will see it be cut off.

Therefore `row` will only grow in height that of the first card in `col-md-10`. Understanding that, you should realize the only thing you need to do is making the `Students` card a `100% height` of its parent; `col-md-2` which' own height is determined by the height of `row`.

In the example below ([or see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qr9jta1g/)) I set a `min-height` on `.card` to give the cards some height for demonstration purposes, but in the end the `Students` card will always grow/shrink to the combined height of its two neighboring cards, except of course when they wrap at the smaller screen size.

```css
.card {
  min-height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <div class="card shadow h-100">
      <div class="card-header">
      <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Students</h6>
      </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          Box C
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
      <div class="card shadow mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Tests</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          content box a
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Questions</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          content box b
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```